# Nhibernate filter tree permissions

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I am trying to create an HQL query that will filter a tree based on a user.

On the tree root i have AllowUsers and AllowRoles and on each node I have DenyUsers and DenyNodes. I can filter to on the user on the root of the tree using

```
select e 
from oStructureMenu e 
  join fetch e.Nodes n 
where e.Id = :id 
  and :user in (select u from e.AllowUsers u)
```

but when I add

```
and :user in (select f.DenyUsers from n f)
```

the sql created has a syntax error

Also I have no idea how I am going to compare the roles for the user to the roles in the allow or deny roles collections

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: What's (select f.DenyUsers from **n** f) ?

Comment: What do you mean by "compare the roles"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shouldn't it be

```
and :user in (select f from n.DenyUsers f)
```

Comment: No, the denyusers is in the nodes not in the root

Comment: but I did change the position of the DenyUsers to the n instead of the f and it worked, thanks! On my other question, how would I compare the contents of the roles collections in HQL?